# Painfully set the sql_mode for vtiger

Tags: mysql, vtiger, my.cnf

I couldn't figure out what Vtiger was on about when it asked me to set the php.ini file to `error_reporting`. Even after the error_reporting had been edited to show;

`error_reporting = E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`

The CRM still persists in telling me it requires resetting, no matter how many time I restarted apache with `sudo apachectl restart`

Anyway...

After moving on, I managed to get to add the database, which at first, looks straight forward, but beware! There's one more huddle to get over before you can successfully install.

You'll probably receive the command to add:

```
 sql_mode = ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Big headache!!

firstly, Mac OS X 10.13.* running MySQL mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64 doesn't own /my.cnf and if like me, you're MySQL file will probably be stored in usr/local/mysql/bin/.

Stop looking, you wont find it anywhere on your Mac...

But there is light at the end of this tunnel...

Comment: You have not asked any question, let alone a question about code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 8):

For Ubuntu - Run command:

`sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Add the following part to the bottom:

```
[mysqld]

sql_mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Run command to restart MySQL Service:

`sudo service mysql restart`

You will also need to change Database Collation to `utf8_general_ci` in phpmyadmin.

Done !

Comment: Just a little help, I'm having the same issue on MySQL 8. Quick fix sql_mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Answer (score 7):

start up terminal and type:

```
sudo pico /etc/my.cnf
```

My.cnf will be empty. Copy and paste this in the file:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Save it (ctrl-x and hit y to accept saving the file) and exit, back into terminal.

Type:

```
sudo touch /etc/my.cnf
```

Then run mysql; `mysql -u root -p`

and check the entry,

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

The result should show the settings you added to my.cnf

Now return to vtiger and continue the installation and it should work :)

Comment: Now that you've answered your own question, would you like to tell the rest of us what it was?

Comment: In Debian 10 the correct path is `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Answer (score 5):

If you use mysql on windows, please edit file [mysql.ini] 
(sample: C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.21\mysql.ini)  
and add below info and then restart mysql service. It's OK

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Comment: Worked in windows !

Answer (score 1):

Fire this query through the root user in MySQL

```sql
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

And check if the settings are applied by firing the query as follows

```sql
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick & Dirty:
edit /modules/Install/Utils.php
Block:   * Function to check sql_mode configuration
Line 349: return false;
change false to true

YOU DISALBE THE CHECK - OWN RISK
Vtiger CRM 7.3.0

Comment: As you mentioned is highly risky but it works. I've use it **but only for a proof of concept**.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Manual Installations]

Find My.ini in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0

Replace

```
sql-mode="ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

note:  MySQL 8.0 does not support NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER (So remove it or sql service would not start)

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to disable it in utils.php as mysql 8.0 doesnt support NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER.